# Print Excel sheets with interchangeable cell value from list and sheet number by copy number

Tags: vba, list, excel, printing

I am trying to optimize paperwork and I can't figure out how to compile two separate macros to work as I need.

On Excel workbook, I have two sheets:

- Sheet1 contains order form (invoice, etc.).
- Sheet2 contains list of product names and quantities.

I need to create a macro so it would take the "Product name" from list (eg. `Sheet2!A1` to `Sheet1!N10`) and change number interchangeable from 1 to "Quantity" (eg. `Sheet2!B1` to `Sheet1!R10`) and print all generated copies through all the list.

For example: `Sheet2!A1` cell contains the product "ALFA" and the corresponding quantity is "3" (cell B1). Next row - A2 contains "BETA" and B2 contains 2 (as quantity)

So the printout will be 5 pages "ALFA - 1", "ALFA - 2", 'ALFA - 3", "BETA - 1", "BETA - 2", and then follow to the next value in the list.

I have found a code (somewhere on internet) to print number of copies with interchangeable number using this code below:

```
Sub Technologiniu_korteliu_kiekis()

    Dim CopiesCount As Long
    Dim copynumber As Long

    CopiesCount = Application.InputBox("How many copies do you want?", Type:=1)
    'Now the program wants you to input how many pages you like to print.
    'You can input 100 here.

    For copynumber = 1 To CopiesCount
        With ActiveSheet
            .Range("L7").Value = copynumber 'I assume your invoice number is in cell E1.
            .PrintOut 'Print the sheet
        End With
    Next copynumber
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to ask a specific question - what are you actually stuck on?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. My macro was creating dublicates. though it wasn't what i need.

```
Sub Macro()

    Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long

    LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 8 To LastRow

        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G6").Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & i).Value
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J7").Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & i).Value

        Dim CopiesCount As Long
        Dim copynumber As Long

        CopiesCount = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E" & i).Value

        If Not Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & i).Value = 1 Then
            For copynumber = 1 To CopiesCount
                With Worksheets("Sheet1")
                    .Range("L7").Value = copynumber
                    .PrintOut
                End With
            Next copynumber
        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```